# Find the coordinates of E, G and H, and calculate the area of shape OFEH

Tags: analytic-geometry

Currently I am looking at a graph of a circle.
The diameter is y=2x+3
Tangent at point E cuts the x-axis at F (12;0)
1. find the coordinates of E
2. find the coordinates of G and H (H being the centre)

You'll find the image useful!
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R12mn.jpg)

Comment: There is an overflow of questions from you... without apparent work. Try first, then say us what you have tried...

Comment: Say us? If I knew how to do the work then trust me I would! I have not looked at graphs like this in years and can't find anything that genuinely helps me figure it out.

Comment: All right: what do you mean when you say "the diameter is $y=2x+3$" ?

Comment: that is the equation of the line known as the diameter.

Comment: Some information is missing. Is the centre of the circle assumed to lie on the $y$-axis?

Comment: I had a look at your figure. Begin by drawing the line with equation $y=2x+3$ in a correct way: it is completely false and you cannot do geometry with completely erroneous figures. For having a precise drawing, use squared paper.

Comment: Thank you, however it was given to me by a teacher (this is just a rough drawing showing the shape) I have all the co-ordinates so the drawing does not matter.

Comment: grand_chat, no, the middle of the circle is point H and the O that lies on the y axis is the origin.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: The diameter lies on the line $y=2x+3$, which has a slope of $2$, so the tangent line has a slope of $-\frac12$. The tangent line contains the point $(12,0)$, so using the point-slope form we get 
$$
y-0=-\frac12(x-12)
$$
as the equation of the tangent line.

(1) The point $E$ is the intersection of the tangent line with the diameter line.

(2) $G$ is the $y$-intercept of the tangent line.

(3) Suppose the centre $H$ of the circle has coordinates $(a,b)$. The centre $H$ lies on the diameter line, so $a$ and $b$ satisfy
$$
b=2a+3.$$
That's one equation for $a$ and $b$. But additional information is needed to completely determine the values of $a$ and $b$. For example, it looks like $H$ lies on the $y$-axis; if so, then this implies that $a=0$, and you can solve for $b$. Without additional information you can imagine infinitely many possibilities for the location of $H$.

(4) The shape $OFEH$ can be viewed as the difference of two triangles, $OFG$ and $HEG$.